# Name of Argument Type

Tags: argumentation

I'm trying to find the name of argument type used in the response to the statement.

> **Statement**: "The Apollo moon landing was a hoax ..."
>
> **Response**: "I'm not familiar with the x, y, z of your claims but IF the
> Apollo landing was a hoax the following would have to be true: 100s,
> if not 1000s of Americans would have had to keep a secret for 50+
> years. The English, the French, the Russians and the Chinese were able
> to track the event. If it was fake why didn't they stand up and say
> so? ....

In effect the response is based upon deductive reasoning that should statement A be true then these following Statements would also be true.

In this case: The Russians and the Chinese (and the British and the French) would know that the moon landing was a hoax and sat upon that information.

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy SE. This sounds like a [reductio ad absurdum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum). Someone says "X". Then you say "Well if X then Y, but we know that not-Y. Since X leads to a contradiction (Y and not-Y), it must be that X is false." It doesn't matter what their reason for X is, if we know it leads to an absurdity then we know it's false.

Comment: @AdamSharpe - yes. I think you're correct. I think you should make that an answer.

Comment: That is purely a Mathematical logic view. In reality I can use if . . . Then format that clearly does not relate the premises to the conclusion. If I drink Dos Equis beer then I am most interesting man in the world. I drink Dos Equis beer. is it necessary that the conclusion follows in reality?  No. You must know what type of logic you refer to. It isn't just LOGIC. There are different types. You also have to understand what logical arguments are. Not every phrase or set of sentences express an argument.  In philosophy an argument typically has two premises and a conclusion.